# Difficulting in accessing information by Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have seen a few videos on the topic of Web Scraping and I wanted to do a personal project on for getting NBA statistics. I tried webscraping it but I don't know how to do it as the data that I am looking for does not appear in my soup object after searching for it.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://bucketlist.fans/#/player_page/2544/ShotChart?"
html_text = requests.get(url).text
print(html_text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, features="lxml")
header = soup.find_all( "h1", {'class':"font-mono font-bold text-center text-3xl m-2"} )
print(header)
```

After inspecting the page, the name of the player should be found in "h1", and class name :"font-mono font-bold text-center text-3xl m-2". Neither does this or any of the stats appear. I have seen tutorials and they always got the information after one or several .find_all(). Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page loads the data from external source in Json format. To load the data into a Pandas DataFrame you can use this example

```py
import pandas as pd

# 2544 is from your URL from the question
url = 'https://bucketlist.fans/api/v1/shot_chart_query?playerIds[0]=2544'

df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| gameId | leagueId | homeTeamId | awayTeamId | seasonId | season | seasonType | gameDate | playerId | teamId | actionType | shotType | shotZoneBasic | shotZoneArea | shotZoneRange | shotDistance | locX | locY | shotMadeFlag | gameEventId | period | minutesRemaining | secondsRemaining | eventMsgId | homeScore | awayScore | description | mediaUuid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21900553 | 1 | 1610612747 | 1610612752 | 22019 | 2019-20 | Regular Season | 2020-01-07 | 2544 | 1610612747 | Step Back Jump shot | 2PT Field Goal | Mid-Range | Left Side Center(LC) | 16-24 ft. | 17 | -143 | 105 | False | 10 | Q1 | 10 | 59 | 2 | 2 | 2 | MISS James 18' Step Back Jump Shot | b0b545bf-70fe-2c60-2522-2e9a9bd98567 |
| 21900553 | 1 | 1610612747 | 1610612752 | 22019 | 2019-20 | Regular Season | 2020-01-07 | 2544 | 1610612747 | Pullup Jump shot | 3PT Field Goal | Above the Break 3 | Right Side Center(RC) | 24+ ft. | 26 | 188 | 188 | True | 50 | Q1 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 6 | James 27' 3PT Pullup Jump Shot (3 PTS) | 76c8dedd-fec2-3914-e7be-47b9c4c58e6a |
| 21900553 | 1 | 1610612747 | 1610612752 | 22019 | 2019-20 | Regular Season | 2020-01-07 | 2544 | 1610612747 | Jump Shot | 3PT Field Goal | Above the Break 3 | Center(C) | 24+ ft. | 25 | 30 | 257 | False | 53 | Q1 | 7 | 37 | 2 | 7 | 6 | MISS James 26' 3PT Jump Shot | bacdc5b7-2879-c4a7-a872-c699c17500bc |
| 41900312 | 1 | 1610612747 | 1610612743 | 42019 | 2019-20 | Playoffs | 2020-09-20 | 2544 | 1610612747 | Jump Shot | 3PT Field Goal | Above the Break 3 | Center(C) | 24+ ft. | 27 | -78 | 267 | True | 14 | Q1 | 11 | 14 | 1 | 3 | 0 | James 28' 3PT Jump Shot (3 PTS) (McGee 1 AST) | 04622c0d-fde5-fa40-e16a-2559eef21b29 |
| 21600001 | 1 | 1610612739 | 1610612752 | 22016 | 2016-17 | Regular Season | 2016-10-25 | 2544 | 1610612739 | Jump Shot | 2PT Field Goal | In The Paint (Non-RA) | Left Side(L) | 8-16 ft. | 11 | -79 | 80 | True | 8 | Q1 | 10 | 59 | 1 | 2 | 4 | James 11' Jump Shot (2 PTS) (Irving 1 AST) | 43b4d94f-db66-cdc1-3d27-179a6c15c9b7 |

Comment: Thank you! What do I need to look for in cases like this where the data is loaded from an external source? I would also like to get data from season averages and game log.

Comment: @afernandezwer When you open in Firefox/Chrome web developer tools, network tab and reload the page, you can see all requests the page is doing. This URL is one amongst them. I believe the averages etc. are computed using JavaScript from this data in the dataframe.